# How to determine the most restrictive SQL server security permissions a program can use and still function?

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

### PROBLEM BACKGROUND

Sorry if this is a bit tedious to read, but please bear with me.

I have been tasked to determine the most restrictive security permissions...or rather investigate if more restrictive security settings can be configured for the SQL server login our program uses, yet still function as normal.

Currently the program runs as a Windows service configured to log on using a Windows user account that has been configured in SQL server with trusted auth. The login used has been assigned a **db_owner** role and the service works fine like that.

So to narrow the permissions for this user I removed the **db_owner** rights and assigned it to the **db_datareader** and **db_datawriter** roles. Unfortunately this causes a problem and when I start up the service I get an error dialogue displaying:

Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

and in the event viewer under the System events are logged:

- event 7009 (timeout waiting for..to connenct)
- event 7000 (the service did not respond to the start or control )

My problem is the code base is really large and I'm not sure what exactly to look for that would require db_owner permissions (it sets permissions maybe?).

---

### QUESTION

What should I be looking for in a program that executes SQL that would cause it to require db_owner permissions?

In case the first question is too general: is there an easy way/any tools I can use to figure out what a Windows service is trying to do during start-up 'SQL wise' if I get system error events logged:

- event 7009 (Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for the ... service to connect)
- event 7000 (The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion).

BTW I tried running profiler with all audit events selected, but still get nothing logged when starting the service.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a broad question without knowing the architecture of your service and how it communicates with SQL Server. Are you using in-line SQL? Stored Procedures?

I think you'd best tackle this issue by starting from the service's code and tracing the execution path from the start and see what is being executed on/against SQL Server.

Alternatively, if you are using stored procedures, you may want to script them all out into a file and search on some common T-SQL commands limited to a db_owner, such as CREATE, DROP, ALTER.

Comment: Sigh I guess that's the only way, I'll have search through the stored procs. It's just strange for me that nothing gets logged in profiler when starting up the service, I'd thought with all events select in profiler something should at least pop up